# Value Error while trying to read json file

Tags: json, django

In Django, I am trying to read the countries to cities json file that's available here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json

I have downloaded the file locally into my static assets folder and I am doing the following to open, read and push all cities into another array

```
obj = []
filename = 'static/json/countriesToCities.json'
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    for key, values in data:
        obj.append(key[0])
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> ValueError at /citiesUrl/
>
> No JSON object could be decoded

How do I push all the values of each key into a new array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use *load* instead *loads* (first for files, second for strings)

I've tested your JSON and it works:

```
json_data = open('/Users/madzohan/Downloads/data.json', 'r')
data = json.load(json_data)
```

Comment: The JSON itself seems sane, I also tested with a browser and the specified URL. There seem to be some UTF issues when you read the file into a string and sending it to `json.loads`.